# pip freeze sets subdirectories

Tags: python, pip, git-submodules, requirements.txt

I have a repository, `myBigRep`, that contains a submodule, `mySmallRep`. This submodule is a python project that has a `setup.py` script that installs some commands. To set it, I run:

```
$ pip install --editable myBigRep/local/src/mySmallRep/
```

And that's it.

Now I want to clone `mySmallRep` somewhere else, set its submodules and install the Python commands. So I first freeze the Python packages:

```
$ cd myBigRep
$ pip freeze 
-e git+git@bitbucket.org:me/mySmallRep.git@d702f237b4c5449dffe5f224a8c361bf983566fc#egg=mySmallRep&subdirectory=../../../../local/src/mySmallRep

$ pip freeze > requirements.txt
$ git add requirements.txt
$ git commit -m "added requirements."
$ git push origin master
```

Now I clone and set everything:

```
$ cd
$ git clone git@bitbucket.org:me/myBigRep.git myBigRepClone
$ cd myBigRepClone
$ git submodule init && git submodule update
$ git submodule foreach git pull origin master
$ pip install --requirement requirements.txt
Obtaining mySmallRep from git+git@bitbucket.org:me/mySmallRep.git@d702f237b4c5449dffe5f224a8c361bf983566fc#egg=mySmallRep&subdirectory=../../../../local/src/mySmallRep (from -r requ.txt (line 2))
  Skipping because already up-to-date.
    Error [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/me/myBigRepClone/src/mySmallRep/../../../../local/src/mySmallRep' while executing command python setup.py egg_info
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/myBigRepClone/local/miniconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/me/myBigRepClone/local/miniconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/home/me/myBigRepClone/local/miniconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/home/me/myBigRepClone/local/miniconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/home/me/myBigRepClone/local/miniconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 518, in _prepare_file
    abstract_dist.prep_for_dist()
  File "/home/me/myBigRepClone/local/miniconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 129, in prep_for_dist
    self.req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "/home/me/myBigRepClone/local/miniconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 439, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "/home/me/myBigRepClone/local/miniconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 667, in call_subprocess
    cwd=cwd, env=env)
  File "/home/me/myBigRepClone/local/miniconda3/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/home/me/myBigRepClone/local/miniconda3/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/me/myBigRepClone/src/mySmallRep/../../../../local/src/mySmallRep'
```

It is obvious the last path is wrong. But if I execute the command manually it works:

```
$ pip install -e git+git@bitbucket.org:me/mySmallRep.git@d702f237b4c5449dffe5f224a8c361bf983566fc#egg=mySmallRep&subdirectory=../../../../local/src/mySmallRep
[1] 19227
Obtaining mySmallRep from git+git@bitbucket.org:me/mySmallRep.git@d702f237b4c5449dffe5f224a8c361bf983566fc#egg=mySmallRep
  Skipping because already up-to-date.
Requirement already satisfied: click in ./local/miniconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from mySmallRep)
Installing collected packages: mySmallRep
  Running setup.py develop for mySmallRep
Successfully installed mySmallRep
```

And if I remove the submodule in the requirement field, it works also:

```
$ pip uninstall mySmallRep -y
Uninstalling mySmallRep-0.1:
  Successfully uninstalled mySmallRep-0.1

$ cat requirements.txt 
-e git+git@bitbucket.org:me/mySmallRep.git@d702f237b4c5449dffe5f224a8c361bf983566fc#egg=mySmallRep&subdirectory=../../../../local/src/mySmallRep

$ cat requirements.txt | sed 's/&subdirectory.*//g'
-e git+git@bitbucket.org:me/mySmallRep.git@d702f237b4c5449dffe5f224a8c361bf983566fc#egg=mySmallRep

$ sed 's/&subdirectory.*//g' -i requirements.txt

$ pip install --requirement requirements.txt 
Obtaining mySmallRep from git+git@bitbucket.org:me/mySmallRep.git@d702f237b4c5449dffe5f224a8c361bf983566fc#egg=mySmallRep (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Skipping because already up-to-date.
Requirement already satisfied: click in ./local/miniconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from mySmallRep->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
Installing collected packages: mySmallRep
  Running setup.py develop for mySmallRep
Successfully installed mySmallRep
```

Why does it put the subdirectory in the first place?

Why processing the subdirectory from the `requirements.txt` file does not work while it does if installed manually?

In an automation context I need to flawlessly freeze packages and to install them from the `requirements.txt` file. A dirty workaround I found is to write the following in my script:

```
$ pip freeze | sed 's/&subdirectory.*//g' > requirements.txt
```

Is there a better way to solve this?